# While using devise and omniauth-facebook, why does facebook show "The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

1. These are my gems.

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook','~> 4.0'
```

2. This is the code I have in my devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SECRET'], scope: 'public_profile,email'
```

3. This is my .env

```
export FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID=<appid>
export FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SECRET=<appsecret>
```

4. I also tried removing the export from the above statements.

```
FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID=<appid>
FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SECRET=<appsecret>
```

5. This is my Facebook application settings.

```
![Facebook app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM8cW.png)
```

6. The same thing works on x branch of my project but the same credentials does not work on the
   branch y of my git project.
7. This is the error I get.

```
Invalid app ID
The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID.
```

Comment: Did you replace <appid> and <appsecret> with your app ID and app secret?

Comment: @WizKid yes i did.

Comment: What is ENV['FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID'] when you run your code?

Comment: Did you remove the angle brackets? It needs to be `FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID=12345`, not `FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID=<12345>`, the brackets are only used to symbolize “this is a placeholder”.

Answer (score 0):

While merging my branch with another it took another branch's omniauth.rb file in the config folder which I think internally overwrote devise.rb and hence did not work.
It was a very very silly error from my end. Thankyou to everyone who answered.